# python Convert a method to a function

Tags: python, methods, md5

Let's say I have an object, called `myMD5`, like this:

```
<md5 HASH object @ 0xb79b9860>
```

And here is `dir(myMD5)`:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'block_size', 'copy', 'digest', 'digest_size', 'digestsize', 'hexdigest', 'name', 'update']
```

I want to get the hash string, and to do that I need to call `myMD5.hexdigest()`. 
The problem is that I'm actually making a challenge (called PyJail) and the use of the character dot (`.`) is forbidden.

So, I need to call this method by another way.
Is there any way to call it like a function ? Something like this:

```
hexdigest(myMD5)
```

I tried to do this, but it does not work:

```
getattr(myMD5, dir(myMD5)[-3]) # returns <classmethod object at 0xb79b998c>
```

PS; Other elements are also forbidden by the challenge, like using quotes (`'`, `"`), using `import` statements, using things like `exec` or `eval`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getattr(myMD5, dir(myMD5)[-3])` returns the method to call, on the object, then you just need to run the method using the parenthesis `()` :

```
myMD5 = md5('fooBar123'.encode("utf-8"))
hexDigestForMyMD5 = getattr(myMD5, dir(myMD5)[-3])

print(hexDigestForMyMD5())                           # dab589b4623e03507d4f094605813ff3
print(md5('fooBar123'.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest())  # dab589b4623e03507d4f094605813ff3
```

Or from [*Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string#answers) you can shorten to

- `getattr(myMD5, dir(myMD5)[-3])()`
- `getattr(myMD5, 'hexdigest')()` as this doesn't return a dot